# Searching across multiple solr instances

Tags: solr

So we have multiple solr instances located in different data centers. Each solr instance has the same collections and schemas, but the data we store in them are different (we only store EU customers in the solr instance located in the EU and we only store US customer data in the solr instance located in the US, etc...).

I'm looking for a way to run a query across all the solr instances in each data center and get a combined result (ie: The final result will contain both EU and US data). I don't want to query each solr instance separately and combine the results on my side since I would like to still be able to use solr's sorting and other query parameters on the final result set.

Does solr have something built in that will help me achieve this? or maybe a third party tool I could use?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways - you can manually use the sharding parameter. First, fetch the set of cores and hosts for [each collection through CLUSTERSTATUS](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-Input.14) in the Collections API (or directly from Zookeeper).

Another option is to use the Solr Streaming Expressions API. There are a few limitations to consider when using the API, and the result set will be formatted differently from the regular query result. The [`search` stream source](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/stream-sources.html#search) allows you to give it the `zkHost` parameter, telling the function what Zookeeper it should contact to get to know where the collection lives and what nodes answers for the collection. After that you'll have to add stream decorators and filters to get the result you want.